# Should I use an infinite loop or a cron job for a python crawler?

Tags: python, cron, web-crawler

I have written a crawler in python that goes over 60 websites, parses HTML, and saves data to Database.

Right now I am using a cron job to run the crawler every 15 minutes. The problem is that I have no way to tell how much it is going to take the crawler to finish (it may take more than 15min sometimes), I don't want to run another crawler if one is already running.

I have been wondering whether I would be better off using an infinite loop and make the crawler a permanent process always running (but how would I make sure the crawler doesn't fail and exit? and how to restart it every time it exits?).

Which one is more efficient? infinite loop or cron job?

Answer (score 0):

you could do a infinite loop in a bash script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
while ((1)) ; do
    python3 -u /path/to/file.py > /path/to/logs.txt
    sleep 2
done
```

it will execute the script, and once the script end(error or not), it will execute again

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521497/how-should-i-run-a-cron-command-which-has-forever-loop

Answer (score 0):

We can add control in the cron job python script to keep track of its running status (e.g. crawl start-time and end-time) in the database.  Using a control structure like this may be easier to maintain:

```py
# query select crawlStartTime and crawlEndTime from DB
# ...
if(crawlEndTime >= crawlStartTime):  # the previous crawl job is finished
    # update DB set crawlStartTime = now
    # do crawling tasks ...
    # crawl finished, update DB set crawlEndTime = now
else:   # the previous crawl job is not finished
    # do not crawl
    # in case the job elapsed for far too long
    if(now - crawlStartTime >= threshold):
        # send alert, kill process, or reset the time records
```